# Content highlighting in solr query results

Tags: solr

In the standard install of solr is a full working example that enables highlighting in search results (named "techproducts"). Here is how to make it work:

1. Install solr
2. CD into install dir:

> cd /usr/local/Cellar/solr/5.5.0

3. Start solr with existing example "techproducts"

> bin/solr -e techproducts

4. Index some example pdfs

> bin/post -c techproducts ~/Desktop/some_pdfs/

5. Go to URL localhost:8983, select the core "techproducts" in the left menu
6. Enter search term in Query field (replace *:* by your query string)
7. Check "hl" field
8. Enter a field name in the field "hl.fl" (for instance: "content")
9. Hit "Execute Query" button

Now you'll see a at the bottom of the result page a context (or snippets) for the search keyword:

> "highlighting": {
>      "/Users/ugur/Desktop/some_pdfs/jQuery Pocket Reference.pdf": {
>        "content": [
>          "  *jQuery* Pocket"
>        ]
>      },
>      "/Users/ugur/Desktop/some_pdfs/jQuery UI.pdf": {
>        "content": [
>          " \n \n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n  \n *jQuery*"
>        ]
>      },
>      "/Users/ugur/Desktop/some_pdfs/jQuery Recipes.pdf": {
>        "content": [
>          " - *jQuery* Recipes  \n \n    \n >"
>        ]
>      }
>    }

I had to look into these two files to see how to make highlighting work for me:

- ./solr/5.5.0/example/techproducts/solr/techproducts/conf/managed-schema

and

- ./solr/5.5.0/example/techproducts/solr/techproducts/conf/solrconfig.xml

---

OLD QUESTION BELOW

I just can't seem to make solr return a context in the query results (highlighting), no matter what I do.

Here is the steps that I followed:

```
brew install solr  # installed it via brew
cd /usr/local/Cellar/solr  # cd'd into the install path
bin/solr start  # started solr // works; can call the URL localhost:8983
bin/solr stop -p 8983 # stopped again
bin/solr -e dih  # started solar with provided example 
bin/post -c tika ~/Desktop/the-effective-engineer-sample.pdf  # posted an example pdf to core "tika"
```

Now if I go to the URL localhost:8983, select the example-core "tika" and fire a query, it works, and I get the document that I have indexed. But if I turn on highlihting (hl = checked), then I get no context in the highlighting section

```
"highlighting": {
    "~/Desktop/the-effective-engineer-sample.pdf": {}
  }
```

Do I need to define a schema.xml? I created one like

```
<schema name='simple' version='1.1'>
    <types>
        <fieldtype name='string' class='solr.StrField' />
    </types>
    <fields>
        <dynamicField name='*' type='string' multiValued='true' indexed='true' stored='true'/>
        <copyField source='*' dest='fulltext'/>
        <field name='fullText' type='string' multiValued='true'/>
    </fields>
    <defaultSearchField>fullText</defaultSearchField>
    <solrQueryParser defaultOperator='OR'/>
</schema>
```

Still I don't get a result in the highlighting section.

Can anyone point me to a simple working tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: You always need a schema.xml.What's your default search field in solrconfig.xml? Try specifying fields to highlight with the hl.fl parameter.

Comment: @DavidG I found a working example in the Solr Reference Guide PDF (https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/ref-guide/). Will update my question above with the working example. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ok I'll take a look